# Generating model through Devise does not add fields - Devise with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I installed devise as instructed. When I did `rails generate devise User` devise does generate user.rb, but it does not write the devise modules and their required fields. 
It only write this inside user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

I used to did the same think before for another application, and for similar command, user.rb is filled with these :

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :validatable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  # field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  # field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  # field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  # field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       type: Time
```

What might I did wrong? What step I may have skipped? I really appreciate for the help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails4,

Add this line in your Gemfile

```
gem 'devise', :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
```

Then run,

```
bundle update
rails generate devise User
```

Now it works fine.